# .toList() is Optional. Why?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In this code I can delete `.toList()` and get the same output. Why is it optional? 
(My theory is because the spread operator is converting the output to a list anyway so `.toList` isn't doing anything...like calling `.toString` on a string.)

If I delete the spread operator and leave `.toList()` I get the error `"type List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Widget"`.
(This invalidates my theory the spread operator and .toList are having the same effect)

I read the previously mentioned error was due to type inference and saw suggestions to put `<Widget>` immediately after `.map` like so: `snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((e)...` however I get a similar error: `List<Widget> is not a subtype of type Widget.`

I'm not asking for anyone to solve a code problem. It's just that I've been coding for less than three months...I'm more looking for an explanation dumbed down enough for a newbie like me to understand.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:ml_app/widgets/shared/loading.dart';

class TodaysReviewScreen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TodaysReviewScreen2State createState() => _TodaysReviewScreen2State();
}

class _TodaysReviewScreen2State extends State<TodaysReviewScreen2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('entries').snapshots(),
      builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Loading();
        }
        return ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              child: Column(children:[
                 ...snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((e) => Text('${e['title']}')).toList(),
              ]),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When you say "If I delete the spread operator and leave `.toList()`", did you also remove the square brackets?  If you just removed the `...`, you'd end up with `[someObject.toList()]` which would be a `List` of a `List`.

Comment: I did not delete the brackets. That makes sense. I'll experiment toggling that in and out. Thanks!

Comment: When you do `[...someObject.toList()]`, that's equivalent to `[...(someObject.toList())]`, so the spread operator unpacks the result of `.toList()` and then `[]` creates another list from the unpacked elements.  So yes, doing `[...someObject.toList()]` is redundant; either use `someObject.toList()` or `[...someObject]`.

Comment: Intuitively that makes sense, but in my experiment without the spread operator I get 1) List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type Widget with the brackets, and 2) List<dynamic> is not a subtype of type List<Widget> without the brackets. So, deleting the spread operator, deleting the brackets, and using toList still causes an error. It appears that was due to type inference because when I added <Widget> immediately after .map it does return as expected. So many variables at play! My head is spinning! Thanks for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spread operator needs an `Iterable`. It will iterate that iterable, and add the elements to the list being created.

Doing `.toList()` on the iterable first will iterate the (potentially lazy) iterable and create a list with the same elements. A `List` is-an `Iterable`, so the spread operator will happily accept the `List` of `.toList()` as well, iterate it *again* and insert the elements into the list being created.

It's not that `.toList()` is optional, as much as that it is *unnecessary*.
You should just *never* call `.toList` on the iterable of a spread operator, or on the argument to `List.addAll` or similar things which consume an iterable.
All that `toList()` does is add an extra iteation, and extra memory allocation for *all* the elements, and then that extra list gets thrown away almost immediately.

Answer (score 1):

> `List<Widget>` is not a subtype of type Widget

I think this log is your answer.

When you use

```
snapshot.data.docs.map<Widget>((e) => Text('${e['title']}'))
```

it will return a `Iterable<Widget>` or `List<Widget>` with `.toList()`.

From [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

> Spread syntax can be used when all elements from an object or array need to be included in a list of some kind.

So the easy explanation is spread syntax will pass your `List<Widget>` one by one to the parent list. In this situation is your `Column(children:[])`.

If you don't use spread syntax, the Column will see your `List<Widget>` as an `Widget` and the Error above will come.

Comment: Ok, with Jamesdlin's response and yours I see four variables at play: toList(), the spread operator, the brackets around the children, and using the explicit type inference. I can get the desired output by 1) using the spread operator with or without toList(), and with or without <Widget> after .map. 2) or, I can delete the spread operator, but I have to also delete the brackets AND I have to add in <Widget> after .map. The second solution changes are needed because the brackets and .toList are redundant (list in a list), and Flutter needs to be told explicitly what the output of the map is.

Answer (score 0):

map() return Iterable,list extends Iterable, children need a list

Comment: I need an apple, so you can't give me a fruit, although Apple belongs to fruit. OOP